# "Value does not fall within the expected range" when adding securables to a SQL Server database user

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to assign securables against a user, but every time I try and grant permissions on a table-valued function, I get the error:

> Key cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key (mscorlib)

There is no error when adding stored procedures, views or tables, and using T-SQL to grant the permissions works fine. I've tried this on different databases on the same server and two instances of SQL Server 2016 with exactly the same errors.

- SQL Server 2016 v13.0.4202.2
- SSMS v16 build 13.0.15900.1
  **Edit:** Upgrade to SSMS 17.1 build 14.0.17119.0 didn't help

As a side note (possibly related), I'm also getting an error when trying to list all objects belonging to a schema via *User > Securables > Search > All objects belonging to the schema*.  It doesn't matter which schema I pick, the dialog closes with the error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range. (SqlMgmt)

More information:

[image: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key (mscorlib)]

Stack trace from the "Technical details" button:

```
===================================

Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key (mscorlib)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Contains(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary.Contains(Object key)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsData.SecurableColumnParent.ApplyRevokes(SqlSmoObject obj)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsData.Principal.ApplyChanges(String principalName, Server server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsDatabasePrincipal.OnRunNow(Object sender)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PanelExecutionHandler.Run(RunType runType, Object sender)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

Comment: You could try clicking the script option to see how it's being executed but looks buggy.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I tried that, but the scripting doesn't even run.  Hence it doesn't appear to be a problem with the executing script itself, but generating the script in the first place.  As I said, manually executing T-SQL commands to do it for me worked fine.

Comment: Looks like a bug in SSMS. As of note, you have a GDR build of SQL Server; the bug might have been introduced in it. Try either a clean SP1 (13.0.4001.0) or the latest CU (13.0.4435.0).

Comment: Thanks @RogerWolf, it certainly looks that way.